# Break After & R Break

Tags: sas

I am creating a report using proc report. My syntax runs fine but it doesnot shows the results of R break & After break in the output report. Thanks in advance

```
ods pdf file = "D:\New folder (2)\Assignment\Case_Study_1\Detail_Report.pdf";                                                        

   proc report data =  Cs1.Detailed_Report headline nowd ls = 256 ps = 765;                                                             

   Title 'Olympic Pipeline (LONDON) - by Probability As of 17th November 2012';                                                         

   column Probability Account_Name Opportunity_Owner Last_Modified_Date Total_Media_Value Digital_Total_Media_Value Deal_Comments;      

   where Probability > 0;                                                                                                               

   define Probability/group Descending 'Probability';                                                                                   

   define Account_Name/order 'Client';                                                                                                  

   define Opportunity_Owner/order 'Champ';                                                                                              

   define Last_Modified_Date/order format = MMDDYY. 'Modified';                                                                         

   define Total_Media_Value/order format = dollar25. 'Tot_Budget';                                                                      

   define Digital_Total_Media_Value/order format = dollar25. 'Digital_Bugt';                                                            

   define Deal_Comments/order 'Deal_Comments';                                                                                          

   break after Probability/ summarize suppress ol ul;                                                                                   

   rbreak after / summarize ol ul;                                                                                                      

   run;                                                                                                                                 

   ods listing close;                                                                                                                   

   ods pdf close;
```

Comment: I don't understand the close vote.  This includes the code that is not working, and an explanation of what's not working.  Not a great question (though better than many) but not valid for that vote.

Comment: Ankit, in the future you'll get better results with in particular code that is runnable by those of us helping you - we don't have the class datasets you do, obviously, so either include the code to create them (as `DATALINES`) or refigure your code to work with a `SASHELP` dataset, like `SASHELP.CARS` or `SASHELP.CLASS` or similar, will help much.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you don't have anything for the summarization to do.  All of your columns are "ORDER" columns, which is probably not what you want.  This is a common confusion in PROC REPORT; `ORDER` actually can be used in two different ways.

- `ORDER` column type (vs. `ANALYSIS`, `GROUP`, `ACROSS`, `COMPUTED`, etc.)
- `ORDER=` instruction for how to order data in a column (`ORDER=DATA`, `ORDER=FORMATTED`, etc.)

You can instruct SAS how to order a column without having to make it an `ORDER` column (which is basically similar to `GROUP` except it doesn't condense extra copies of a value if there are more than one).

If you want `RBREAK` or `BREAK` to do anything, you need to have an `ANALYSIS` variable(s); those are the variables that you want summaries (and other math) to work on.

Here is an example of this working correctly, with `analysis` variables.  You need to tell SAS what to do, also, when summarizing them; `mean`, `sum`, etc., depending on what your desired result is.

```
ods pdf file = "c:\temp\test.pdf";                                                        
   proc report data =  sashelp.cars headline nowd ls = 256 ps = 765;                                                             
   column cylinders make model invoice mpg_highway mpg_city;      
   where cylinders > 6;                                                                                                               
   define cylinders/group Descending;                                                                                   
   define make/order;                                                                                                  
   define model/order;                                                                                              
   define invoice/analysis sum;                                                                         
   define mpg_highway/analysis mean;                                                                      
   define mpg_city/analysis mean;                                                            
   break after cylinders/ summarize suppress  ol ul;                                                                                   
   rbreak after / summarize ol ul;                                                                                                      
   run;                                                                                                                                 
ods pdf close;
```